# Iterate array objects in js

Tags: javascript

I have an array objects
it looks like

```
\[
{id: 1, name: 'first', properties: \[{id: 1, name: 'propName1'}, {id: 2, name: 'propName2'}\]},
{id: 2, name: 'second', properties: \[{id: 1, name: 'propName1'}, {id: 2, name: 'propName2'}\]},
{id: 3, name: 'third', properties: \[{id: 1, name: 'propName1'}, {id: 2, name: 'propName2'}\]},
\]
```

I want to display first name of object for example 'first' and then I want to display names of properties objects propName1, propName2
so I want to see

first

propName1
propName2

second

propName1
propName2

third

propName1
propName2

Could you help me, guys?

I tried

```
{filters.map((filter) => {
  let propss = ArrayFrom(filter.properties);
  propss.map((prop) => (
    <div>{prop.displayName}</div>
  ))

  return(
    <div className={style.title}>{filter.displayName}</div>
  )

  filter.properties.map((prop) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className={style.title}>{filter.displayName}</div>
        <div>{prop.displayName}</div>
      </>
    );
  });
})}
```

and I tried to save array via reduce, but without any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not name yout array 'filter' since this can be confused with the Array.prototype.filter method ;)

Then you have an array of objects containing arrays, so you should iterate at the two level (in case your real structure actually gots more depth, you probably need to take a recursive approach).

considering your entry point :

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'first',
    properties: [
      {id: 1, name: 'propName1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'propName2'}
    ]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'second',
    properties: [
      {id: 1, name: 'propName1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'propName2'}
    ]
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'third',
    properties: [
      {id: 1, name: 'propName1'},
      {id: 2, name: 'propName2'}
    ]
  },
]
```

the two iterations couls look like somthing like that :

```
return data.map(entry => (
  <>
    <div className={style.title}>{entry.name}</div>
    {entry.properties.map(prop => (
      <div>{prop.name}</div>
    ))}
  <>
))
```

Comment: I dont know why and where I made mistake, but I thought like you, but I had not result. Your solution helped me, thanks a lot!